# How to get ng-model data from a input into a state.go() call with ng-click on a button?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an input field and a button.  I'd like the text from the input to be sent to my controller someway or another.

I have tried this.  The state transition works, the view loads, but `searchText` doesn't make its way into my controller.  I've tried a few things passed to `$state.go()`, like just `searchText` and even `{{searchText}}`

```
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" ng-model="searchText">
        </div>
        <button ng-click="$state.go('app.search', $scope.searchText)" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

My state config looks like this:

```
            .state('app.search', {
                url: 'search/:searchText',
                views: {
                    'MainPane@': {
                        templateUrl: 'views/content/search.html',
                        controller: 'SearchController'
                    }
                }
            })
```

and my controller for now:

```
angular.module('SearchController', [])
.controller("SearchController", ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$state', '$http',
    function ($scope, $stateParams, $state, $http) {

        console.log($stateParams);

    }]);
```

update:  tried the suggestions in the comments.  This turned out to work.  Using $scope.searchText did not work.

```
   {'searchText': searchText})
```

Comment: the [docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#toparams) indicate an object map is needed `{ searchText: searchText }`

Comment: As @calebboyd mentioned, you have to pass parameters like this: $state.go('app.search', {'searchText': $scope.searchText})

Comment: As specified in the docs, you can also use [**ui-sref**](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref#usage) with any element. So it would have been perfectly fine to use `ui-sref="app.search({searchText: searchText})"`

Comment: @adapt-dev: All members of `$scope` are available to use on templates, but `$scope` itself not. Either use ui-sref or place it inside a function on controller.